# Aligning navigation links evenly bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following nav bar

[image]

As you can see either side of the logo in the middle, there is a great deal of white space ideally I would like to space the navigation links out evenly so it would look something like this

[image]

I have achieved what is shown in the second picture by using padding-left and padding-right which to me seems a bit of a hack, I've googled looking for a potential solution for this but with no avail. this is my current html you can see the padding I have entered.

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down pull-right"></span>
            </button>
        </div>

        <a class="navbar-brand visible-lg visible-md hidden-sm hidden-xs"
           style="background-image: url('/Content/Images/logo.png'); background-repeat: no-repeat; height: 94px; width: 301px; left: calc(50% - 148px); "
           href='@Url.Action("Index", "Home")'></a>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                <li id="lnkProducts">@Html.ActionLink("PRODUCTS", "Products", "Products")</li>
                <li><a href="/flavour-lab" style="font-family: Foco-Regular; padding-left: 35%" class="paddingLeft">FLAVOUR LAB</a></li>
            </ul>

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="/our-story" style=" font-family: Foco-Regular;padding-right:45%">OUR STORY</a></li>
                <li id="lnkVisitUs"><a href="#" target="_blank" style=" font-family: Foco-Regular">VISIT US: <b>f</b></a></li>
                <li id="lnkContactUs" class="visible-xs-block">@Html.ActionLink("CONTACT US", "Contact", "Contact") </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Thanks

** Update **

As requested please see below CSS for left and right nav bar

```
   .navbar-left {
    float: left !important;
}

.navbar-right {
    float: right !important;

}
```

** Update **

This is whats shown when minimized to a mobile screen

[image]

Comment: can you post the css too? specially the css for  `class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left"` and `class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right"`

Comment: better yet, drop it in a bootply

Comment: @AdityaPonkshe added the CSS

Comment: @ScottAtkinson Is it acceptable to add specific width to `.navbar-left` and `.navbar-right`

Comment: @AdityaPonkshe if it works and doesn't affect the mobile version when viewed then sure I don't see why not.

Comment: @ScottAtkinson If you can add width to `.navbar-left` & `.navbar-right` . You can add `float:left` to the first menu and `float:right` to the second one. It will work just fine IMO. I would have made an example for you but I'll need HTML and CSS for whole heading.

Comment: @AdityaPonkshe I added a width of 380px to .navbar-left and .navbar-right you can see in the CSS I provided it already had the float yet the left nav has stayed the same, yet the right nav has come in a bit

Comment: @ScottAtkinson I mean add `float` `left` and `right` to the <li> elements inside the '.navbar-right' and '.navbar-left'

Comment: @ScottAtkinson Chekc my answer see if it works for you

Comment: @AdityaPonkshe I've done that, it works, but when I view this on a mobile the menu navigation is all over the place so I don't think this would be a suitable solution

Comment: @ScottAtkinson Then don't use width in hard coded px. use calc function.

Comment: @scottAtkinson Can you give me the size of that middle icon?

Comment: @AdityaPonkshe height: 94px width: 301px

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add width to your `.navbar-left` and `.navbar-right` to do this. and then add floats to the inner elements.

For example

```
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left" style="width:380px">
        <li style="float:left" id="lnkProducts">@Html.ActionLink("PRODUCTS", "Products", "Products")</li>
         <li><a href="/flavour-lab" style="font-family: Foco-Regular; float:right" class="paddingLeft">FLAVOUR LAB</a></li>
     </ul>
```

UPDATE -

If giving width in `PX` to your `navbar` is not working in mobile you can use `calc` function in css to give the width. If the size of your middle icon is `301px*91px` use following `width` for your left and right navbars

```
width: -webkit-calc(50% - 150px);
```

Comment: sorry where would I add width: -webkit-calc(50% - 150px); on to the LI?

Comment: ok done that, I've attached a picture to show you what it looks like on the mobile screen

Comment: and is it working fine if you remove `width: -webkit-calc(50% - 150px);` from your classes?

Comment: yes, but when viewed on the mobile some links appear the right hand side, whilst the others appear the left hand side

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not be considered a hackish solution, depending on your need, but if you also need it to be responsive I'd probably go with table-display.

Yes, I know. But it keeps the layout clean and it works, at least until your logo's width is less than 20% of the container's width.

HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <div class="nav navbar-nav">
                <div>link1</div>
                <div>link2</div>
                <div class="text-center">logo</div>
                <div class="r">link3</div>
                <div class="r">link4</div>
            </divv>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
.navbar-nav { display: table; }
.navbar-nav > div { display: table-cell; width: 20%; }
.navbar-nav > div.r { text-align: right; }
```

The other thing to manage with this approach is that you have to build another, separate menu for the fluid viewport and switch between the two depending on screen size.